# The face recognition function

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I Am Using cv2 and following is the code .

```
# OpenCV trains a model from the images
# NOTE FOR OpenCV2: remove '.face'
model = cv2.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
model.train(images, labels)
```

The error that showing up upon running this program is

```
model = cv2.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's under `face` class:

```
model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

for more info see [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d25/classcv_1_1face_1_1LBPHFaceRecognizer.html)